# Rails-Redirect to different paths based on form input during create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a create action in my controller.

```
 def create

        @client=Client.find(params[:client_id])
        @comment= @client.build_comment( comment_params )
        if @comment.save

        flash[:success]= "Thank you!"
        redirect_to path_one
        else
            render action: :new
        end

    end
        private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:response, :experience)
        end
```

Now in my create action, whenever my client submits the form, I want to be able to redirect to different paths based on the value of "experience".

So, if the experience is "positive", I want them to go to path_one and if the experience is "negative", I want them to go to path_two.

I tried this:

```
def create

        @client=Client.find(params[:client_id])
        @comment= @client.build_comment( comment_params )
        if @comment.save
             if params[:experience]=="positive"

                  flash[:success]= "Thank you!"
                  redirect_to path_one
                  else
                  render action: :new
             else
             redirect_to path_two
        end
        end 
end
        private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:response, :experience)
        end
```

But this always redirects to the same path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if @comment.save
  if comment_params[:experience]=="positive"
    flash[:success]= "Thank you!"
    redirect_to path_one
  else
    redirect_to path_two
  end
else
  render action: :new
end
```

the field experience is not inside params, but inside params[:comment] (or, in this case, inside the comment_params method)

Answer (score 0):

The `else` parts of your if statement are in the wrong order. Try this:

```
if @comment.save
  if params[:experience]=="positive"
    flash[:success]= "Thank you!"
    redirect_to path_one
  else
    redirect_to path_two
  end
else
  render action: :new
end
```

Comment: Tried it. Always redirects to path_two.

Comment: Then that would indicate that whatever is in params[:experience] is not equal to "positive"

Comment: params[:experience] is from the same create action. Can I even do something like that? I am using the params[:experience] which is one of the attributes that will be created. I tried with both "negative" and "positive".